# PHP change order in Array with foreach

Tags: php

```
$fruit = array(0 => "Lemon", 1 => "Apple");
$order = array(0 => "no1", 1 => "no2");
$new_array = array();
foreach ($order as $index) {
    $new_array[$index] = $fruit[$index];
}
print_r($new_array);
```

**It shows:**

```
Notice: Undefined index: no1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\jobs.php on line 6
Notice: Undefined index: no2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\jobs.php on line 6
```

What should I do?
Thank you :)

Comment: Please include what your desired output would be

Comment: I would like to make this Array ( [no1] => Lemon [no2] => Apple)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `array_combine()` function available in PHP ([see PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)) :

> "array_combine — Creates an array by using one array for keys and
>   another for its values"

```
$fruit = array(0 => "Lemon", 1 => "Apple");
$order = array(0 => "no1", 1 => "no2");
$new_array = array_combine($order, $fruit);
print_r($new_array);
```

> // Output : Array ( [no1] => Lemon [no2] => Apple )

Working example: https://3v4l.org/rW71r

Comment: You're welcome, next time, you should add your expected output in your original post :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you need to use the key of the loop and use that to get the fruit, just keep in mind that you will get a notice if the key doesn't exist as you did above.

```
$fruit = array(0 => "Lemon", 1 => "Apple");
$order = array(0 => "no1", 1 => "no2");
$new_array = array();
foreach ($order as $key => $index) {
    $new_array[$index] = $fruit[$key];
}
print_r($new_array);
```